# POST and DELETE a booking using OutlookClient and Outlook Calendar API

Tags: android, ms-office, android-sdk-2.3, outlook-restapi, outlook-calendar

I'm using [Outlook-SDK-Android](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-SDK-Android) ([MS](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/android)) to talk with [Outlook Calendar REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations).

So far I've been able to get the events from my calendar using:

```
        import com.microsoft.services.outlook.fetchers.OutlookClient;

        OutlookClient mClient;
        ...
        mClient = new OutlookClient(outlookBaseUrl, mResolver);

        final List<Event> events = mClient
            .getMe()
            //.getUsers()
            //.getById("meetingRoom@company.com") // This gives me back 403 :(
            .getCalendarView()
            .addParameter("startDateTime", startDate)
            .addParameter("endDateTime", endDate)
            .read()
```

(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585155/get-user-calendar-using-outlookclient)).

Question now is:

- How can I use OutlookClient to add a booking?

( **POST** [https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars/{calendar_id}/events](http://fake.com) - from [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#Createevents))

- What about deleting a calendar event instead?

( **DELETE** [https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events/{event_id}](http://fake2.com) - from [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#Deleteevents) )

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hints received from one of the Outlook SDK Android authors (Marcos Torres - Microsoft Venezuela), it simply is:

**Create event​:**

```
Event addedEvent = client.getMe()
                         .getCalendars().getById("Calendar").getEvents().add(event).get();
```

​
**Delete event​:**

```
client.getMe().getEvents().getById(addedEvent.getId()).delete().get();
```

See [e2e test](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-SDK-Android/blob/master/tests/e2e-test-app/app/src/main/java/com/microsoft/outlook/test/integration/tests/ExchangeTests.java#L2021).

Worth bear in mind though that *"We're not maintaining the SDK anymore. By the way, by early April (Build Conference) a new SDK will be released. While may not be covering all the Outlook API surface now, it will be in the future."*

And also *"Keep in mind the SDK was code-generated from the endpoint-metadata. If by any chance the metadata (hence the service) change, the SDK won't work."*